When $x$ tends to $3$ is $x+3$ always less than $6$ or not?
In a question, it was asked to prove that as limit $x$ goes to $3$, $x^{2}$ tends to $9.$
Now, on solving it by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method, when I simplified $x^{2} - 9$ to $\left(x-3\right)\left(x+3\right)$ and put $x+3$ to be $6$ because $x+3$ will always be less than $6$ (to get a suitable $\delta$) and by this, my $\delta$ came out to be $\epsilon/6.$
But in the actual solution they used that $x+3$ will be less than $7$ as $x$ tends to $3$. But isn't choosing $6$ more accurate or am I missing something?

x can be greater than 3.

$|x -3| < \delta$ that means that $x$ "approach" the limit from "both sides".

$x+3$ will be less than $7$ (and more than $5$) if $x$ is sufficiently close to $3$; more precisely: if $|x-3|<1$.

In an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof there is no reason to attempt to find the “best” $\delta$. It is often very useful to use pretty crude estimates. In this case the $7$ could be replaced by $8$ or $6.5$, for example.

Consider $~x = 3.00000000001.$

It is certainly not true that $x+3$ will always be less than $6$. But what you can say is that if $|x-3|<\delta$, then $|(x+3)-6| = |x-3|<\delta$.
So, if you bound your $\delta$ by saying that $\delta < 1$, then you can be sure that $(x+3)$ is at most $1$ away from $6$, in other words, $x+3\in(5,7)$.

Recall that for $B>0$
$$|A|\le B \iff -B\le A\le B$$
therefore
$$|x-3|<\delta \iff -\delta<x-3<\delta \iff -\delta+6<x+3<\delta+6$$
that is $x\in(6-\delta,6+\delta)$.
